# Как создать заглушку функции в lambda стиле?

Tags: python, функции, lambda

Я создал класс дерева, которое отслеживает количество элементов во внутренней переменной `length`. В конструкторе этого класса я передаю `hook`-функцию, которая изменяет `length` родительского элемента дерева всякий раз, когда изменяется количество элементов дочернего дерева.

```
class Tree(list):
    def __init__(self, change_length_hook=lambda *_:None, *args, **kwds):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.length = 0
        self._change_length_hook = change_length_hook

    def _change_length(self, cnt:int=1, ml:int=1):
            self.length += cnt * ml
            self._change_length_hook(cnt, ml)
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Tree):
            self._change_length(other.length)
            return self.__class__(self + other)
        
        self._change_length(len(other))
        return self.__class__(self + list(other))
```

---

Я бы хотел иметь какую-нибудь заглушку для корневого дерева, которая принимает любое количество параметров, и не делает ничего при вызове, чтобы я мог указать её в качестве параметра по умолчанию, для функции `_change_length_hook`, чтобы её вызов не был проблемой для корня дерева.

---

Таким образом я хотел бы что-то вроде `lambda *_, **_: None`, но это не работает. Любые предложения?

Comment: `pass` не подойдет?

Comment: pass не работает в лямдах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй массив для колбэков. Так решится проблема почему лямбда не работает и она же переснат быть нужна.

```
class Tree(list):
    def __init__(self, change_length_hook=None, *args, **kwds):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.length = 0
        self._change_length_hook = []
        if change_length_hook:
            self._change_length_hook.append(change_length_hook)

    def _change_length(self, cnt:int=1, ml:int=1):
            self.length += cnt * ml
            for hook in self._change_length_hook: hook(self,cnt, ml)
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Tree):
            self._change_length(other.length)
            return self.__class__(self + other)
        
        self._change_length(len(other))
        return self.__class__(self, list(other))
```

Comment: Мне не выгодно хранить массив в каждой ветке дерева, кроме того, синтаксис весьма громоздкий. Простите, но это не отвечает на мой вопрос.

Comment: Чёрт возьми, мне действительно понадобился список коллбэков, на тот случай, если узел принадлежит сразу нескольким деревьям... Ты был прав, отмечу это как ответ.

Comment: Массив тут в первую очередь для того чтоб не сохранять функцию в атрибуте. ведь при вызове с атрибута в список аргументов может добавляться или не добавляться self.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге я использовал:

```
class Tree(list):
    ''' Represent tree '''

    def blank_func_kwds(**_):
        pass

    def blank_func(*_, **__):
        __class__.blank_func_kwds(**__)
    
    def __init__(self, change_length=blank_func):
        ...
```

Спасибо [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1541798/369677) eri, он натолкнул меня на мысль, что использовать lambda выражения в данном случае, не стоит.

Согласно [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) , вы должны «всегда использовать оператор def вместо оператора присваивания, который привязывает лямбда-выражение непосредственно к имени»

Хотя, если вам интересно, это - `lambda *_, **__: (lambda **_:None)(**__)` тоже работает

Comment: а зачем вызываете обработчик на blank_func_kwds ? он тут не нужен. можно сразу pass.

Comment: @eri Меня раздражают неиспользуемые параметры, но да, вы правы.

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж возвращать `None`, как в ответе **@Aycon**, то почему бы не так:

```py
lambda *_, **__: None
```

?

Comment: Аргументы не используются, это предупреждение.